# CKEditor issue - "Browse Server" button disappears when using external CSS sheet

Tags: css, ckeditor

I have CKEditor installed and working fine.

I wanted to be able to use the style sheet of the website I have CKeditor installed in within the content area of the CKEditor itself so that the experience is truly WYSIWYG so after searching the web I found that I could do that by adding these two lines, which I did:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.add
var editor = CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = '/userdata/tbs.css' ;
```

It did achieve the results I was hoping, except that now my "Browse Server" button inside the CKEditor window that you get when, for example, you want to add an Image, disappeared...

I thought that something in my CSS file was doing that so I removed the contents of the CSS file completely but the Button is still gone.

If I remove those two lines of code then the button comes back, but if I leave the two lines there the button disappears, whether the CSS file has any definitions or is completely blank.

Can you guys help me?
​

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution and wanted to answer my own post in case somebody stumbles upon this with the same problem.

The line:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'mydata' );
```

needs to be AFTER the lines:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.add
var editor = CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = '/my.css' ;
```

Initially I had it before and so it wasn't working.

Basically in the end my code looks like this:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.add
var editor = CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = '/my.css';
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'mydata' );
CKFinder.setupCKEditor( editor, '/ckfinder/' );
```

Answer (score 0):

actually I found out I was wrong and the actual correct code to use is this:

```
CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = '/my.css';
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'mydata' );
CKFinder.setupCKEditor( editor, 'my/ckfinder/' );
```